# SetWindowPos centers window when position is adjacent to working area border

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, mfc, win32gui

I'm trying to place dialog window adjacent to desktop's top or bottom border.

Code:

```
CRect MonitorWorkingArea(HMONITOR monitor)
{
    MONITORINFOEX monInfo;
    zeroVar(monInfo);
    monInfo.cbSize = sizeof(monInfo);
    GetMonitorInfo(monitor, &monInfo);

    return monInfo.rcWork;
}

CRect MonitorWorkingArea_Wnd(HWND hwnd)
{
    return MonitorWorkingArea(MonitorFromWindow(hwnd, MONITOR_DEFAULTTONEAREST));
}

CRect MonitorWorkArea_Wnd(CWnd& wnd)
{
    return MonitorWorkingArea_Wnd(wnd.GetSafeHwnd());
}

void CMyDialog::SetDefaultWndPos(bool toBottom)
{
    // Here we can be sure, that
    // a) parent of this window is not null, is visible, not minimized
    // b) this window smaller than working area of desktop
    // c) it has WS_POPUP style

    CRect rcThis;
    GetWindowRect(&rcThis);

    // Shift our rectangle to most upper or most bottom position
    const CRect rcDesktop = MonitorWorkingArea_Wnd(*this);
    rcThis.MoveToY(toBottom ? rcDesktop.bottom - rcThis.Height() : 0);

    // Move window
    SetWindowPos(NULL, rcThis.left, rcThis.top, 0, 0,
        SWP_NOSIZE | SWP_NOZORDER | SWP_NOACTIVATE);
}
```

Real code is bit more complex, I omit some checks and features for simplicity.

I have two monitors, both are 1920×1080 and in virtual coordinate space they are laying on:

- Primary: (0,0) — (1920,1080)
- Secondary: (1920,0) — (3840, 1080)

Code above works fine when window placed on primary monitor, but on secondary one it's works unexpectedly: it centers window based on it's parent.

For instance I'm calling `SetDefaultWndPos(false)` and rcThis being calculated as `{left:2710, top:0, right:3423, bottom:550}`. So `SetWindowPos` is called with zero `y`:

```
    SetWindowPos(NULL, 2710, 0, 0, 0,
        SWP_NOSIZE | SWP_NOZORDER | SWP_NOACTIVATE);
```

But in handler of `WM_WINDOWPOSCHANGING`

```
void CMyDialog::OnWindowPosChanging(WINDOWPOS* lpwndpos)
{
    __super::OnWindowPosChanging(lpwndpos);
}
```

I see in debug `x = 2710` (unchanged) and `y = 475` (unexpected). Next I check dialog's y-position in Spy utility, it's 475. Dialog window looks like it was centered on it's parent window.

All it looks like an OS errorneously detected requested window position as out-of-desktop and used some default positioning.

Only workarund I found is to decrease desktop working area on 1 pixel from each side:

```
CRect MonitorWorkingArea(HMONITOR monitor)
{
    MONITORINFOEX monInfo;
    zeroVar(monInfo);
    monInfo.cbSize = sizeof(monInfo);
    GetMonitorInfo(monitor, &monInfo);

    CRect rc = monInfo.rcWork;
    if( !(monInfo.dwFlags & MONITORINFOF_PRIMARY) )
    {
        ++rc.left;
        ++rc.top;
        --rc.right;
        --rc.bottom;
    }

    return rc;
}
```

It works but looks as strange ugly hack.

Can anybody explain what happens here and help me with good decision?

Can it be OS version dependent? (I use Windows 7 Professional SP1).

Comment: Does the behavior change, when you add the `SWP_NOSENDCHANGING` flag? The first thing I would try is to write a plain Windows API [mcve], though, to eliminate MFC as a potential source. Even though MFC usually just forwards calls to the Windows API, there's a lot of code hidden in strange places.

Comment: `SWP_NOSENDCHANGING` flag has attracted my attention and I tryed to add this but behaviour didn't chaged. It seems that at the time of `WM_WINDOWPOSCHANGING` send all the dirty things are happened.
I like idea to exclude potential MFC influence and I will try to reproduce the issue on pure Win API a little bit later, it need some time.